# Joining array to string from list comprehension results in join between all characters

Tags: python, list, django-1.5

So I have the following dict (the reason it's a dict and not a list is due to the output of the `queryparams-parser` django package parsing POST values:

```
doctor_times = {
    '1': {
        'id': 'ABC',
    },
    '2': {
        'id': 'DEF',
    },
}
```

The plan is to merge these to a string such as `"'ABC', 'DEF'"` for which I thought the following code would do:

```
doctorcodes = ', '.join("'%s'" % [str(doctor_times[k]['id']) for k in doctor_times.keys()])
```

However this results in:

```
"[, ', A, B, C, ', ,,  , ', D, E, F, ', ]"
```

If I remove the `'%s' %` component however it works fine, but I do need them wrapped individually in quotes.

Comment: The `doctor_times` dict you show is not valid. You probably need quotes around `ABC` and `DEF` if those are actually strings. Also, do you really want the inner quotation marks in the combined string? Do you care what kind of quotation marks they are?

Comment: You're right, I missed a few quotes throughout the question, I'll update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, you are passing the entire list to `'%s' %` part. Instead move it only to the string part like this.

```
print ', '.join(['%s' % str(doctor_times[k]['id']) for k in doctor_times.keys()])
```

and you don't need to format the data to `str` again with `%s`. So, it becomes like this

```
print ', '.join(str(doctor_times[k]['id']) for k in doctor_times.keys())
```

This could be further simplified like this

```
print ", ".join(str(v['id']) for v in doctor_times.values())
```

Comment: Ahh yes silly me, thanks for point out the obvious. Thanks for the alternative as well though, much nicer.

Comment: Ahh, the `str()` is because it's possible the string maybe be [0-9] in the POST request, which queryparser interprets as numeric.

Comment: Is there a reason for the `format` call in the last version? surely `str(v[id])` would be simpler. Or maybe use `repr` if you want quotation marks around the inner strings.

Comment: @Blckknght Oh yeah. `str` itself is enough. I had that because, I was printing with quotes before, thats why I used `format`. Updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a more generic approach by nesting the call to `dict.values` on the `values` of the dictionary. What you have is a two depth nested dictionary, but arbitrary depth, the following solution can easily be adopted

```
>>> ','.join(str(e[0]) for e in map(dict.values, doctor_times.values()))
'ABC,DEF'
```

or if you prefer `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import imap, chain
>>> ', '.join(map(str, chain.from_iterable(imap(dict.values, doctor_times.values()))))
'ABC, DEF'
```

Comment: values can be numbers as well, not just strings.

Comment: Yes can be though, which you solution does considers.

Comment: Even I didnt consider that initially, he explained why he uses `str` in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want:

```
", ".join(repr(v["id"]) for v in doctor_times.values())
```

This will join the values in an arbitrary order though. If you want the order to be consistent (always `"'ABC', 'DEF'"` and never `"'DEF', 'ABC'"`), you may instead need to sort the dictionary items, rather than just iterating over the values directly:

```
", ".join(repr(v["id"]) for k, v in sorted(doctor_times.items()))
```

There is one more potential issue with this code. If some of your strings have single quote characters in them (and no double quote characters), their `repr` will use double quotes, rather than single ones. If a string includes both single and double quotes, the single quote characters will be escaped with `\`. If the joined string needs to follow some specific convention (such as the rules of a programming language or a data protocol), you may need to use your own escaping code, rather than relying on `repr`.

Comment: we don't need `k` and `items`.

Comment: @thefourtheye: `k` and `items` are needed for the sorting. The `k, v` tuples will be sorted by `k` values (with the values ignored, since dictionary keys are guaranteed to be unique).

Comment: Um, I explain why sorting might be desired in the answer. If it doesn't matter whether you get `'"ABC", "DEF"'` or `'"DEF", "ABC"'` then the first version of the code, which doesn't use `items()` is good enough.

Comment: I get why you are doing that :) But OP hasn't mentioned anything about the order in the question. So, this might be a new requirement. :)